# Nonlinear regression: improving parameter estimates

Tags: regression, estimation, least-squares, nonlinear-regression, nonparametric

I'm running a nonlinear regression to estimate $\delta$ and $\alpha$ using the following model, where $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are the variables:
\begin{equation}
Z = \left(\delta X^\alpha+(1-\delta)Y^\alpha\right)^{1/\alpha}
\end{equation}
The model converges to a solution, but the estimates are too far from reasonable values stated in the literature. In particular, the estimate for $\delta$ is close to zero and the one for $\alpha$ is about 11, where in fact $\delta$ is expected be around 0.3-0.5 and $\alpha$ within 0.8-1.0.

I tried setting $\delta=0.4$ and estimating $\alpha$ only, in which case I got a much better result as the $\alpha$ estimate in this case was close to 1.0. Of course, the sum of squared errors was higher but R-squared dropped very little.

I am looking for any advice on what to make of this situation. I am getting a much more reasonable $\alpha$ estimate by forcing $\delta=0.4$, which is itself a reasonable value for $\delta$. By sacrificing some goodness of fit (although R-squared is little affected), I'm getting a meaningful result. How should I act in this case? Is there a general approach to this sort of situations? Is there a common way of doing sensitivity analysis with parameter estimates in the context of nonlinear least squares? Any comment is welcome.

To give more context, the purpose is to fit a utility curve based on individuals' choices between a riskless outcome and risky lottery. Each individual is asked 6 questions (so 6 observations per subject) and we have close to 100 individuals in the study (roughly 600 observations in total). The nonlinear regression yields reasonable estimates when individiuals' responses are pooled (i.e., sample size = 600) but gives me quite extreme values for some subjects. For example, the following is responses by a particular subject. For this subject, my $\delta$ and $\alpha$ estimates are .0005 and 10.4, respectively, both of which are very extreme, while the subject's preferences are not so extreme.

### [image: data]

Comment: It would be good to know more about your data, the assumptions about the errors, and the procedure you are using to fit them.  Barring that, in any event you might consider reparameterizing this model so that $\delta$ is unconstrained.  A good choice often is $\delta = 1/(1 + \exp(\delta^\prime))$ for $\delta^\prime\in\mathbb{R}.$ Start the search at $(\delta^\prime,\alpha)=(0,1).$

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: I have added some data and explained the context. I used the "nl" command in Stata for estimating the model. I will run the model in Mathematica too as it seems Mathematica offers more choice on the procedure of estimation.

Comment: A few things to try:  1) Plot your data and fitted model in a spreadsheet in a way that you can tweak the parameters and the line for the model will change automatically.  You might be able to hone delta and alpha together to fit the data reasonably well and be in the expected ranges.  Feeding these starting parameters into your software might convince it to converge where you want it to. 2) Change the fitting algorithm, for example from Gauss-Newton to Levenberg-Marquardt.  3) Try a different fitting technique like orthogonal nonlinear least-squares regression.